# Weird Issue when installed

Tags: vb.net, console

I have created a console application that is every simple. Basically, I will run each Monday to generate a report per director with only their employee's data. Each week it checks to see if the directory for that date exists (I am saving the files in a folder named as the date), and deletes if it is there and creates it if not. (in case it is kicked off 2x in same day). It then populates an excel spreadsheet template with data from a SQL database (ADODB connection), and saves it to that directory. It works perfectly fine in VS, I created an installation package and installed it on my server, and the .exe works perfectly if executed manually. The problem I am running into is scheduling it. I have tried both SQL Job (Operating system (CmdExec) that kicks of a bat file, and I have tried a scheduled task. Both run into the same issue, they will delete the directory, and re-create the folder, but will not execute the rest of the code. Any thoughts?  Here is the code:  `
Public Class GenerateReport

```
Public Sub Excel()


    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim DirectorID As String
    Dim DirectorFullName As String


    Dim DateStamp As String
    Dim currentTime As System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
    Dim createreportfolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim appPath As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim OpenPath As String




    Try

        'createreportfolder = appPath

        createreportfolder = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SaveToPath")

        DateStamp = CStr(currentTime.Month & "-" & currentTime.Day & "-" & currentTime.Year)
        createreportfolder = createreportfolder + DateStamp

        'CREATE NEW DIRECTORY FOR REPORTS 

        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(createreportfolder) Then
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(createreportfolder, True)
        End If

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createreportfolder)

        strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT DirectorID,DirectorFullName FROM tLogClockComparisonReport ORDER BY 1 "



        conn.Open("Provider=SQLNCLI11; Initial Catalog=Operations; Data Source=")
        conn.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        rs.Open(strSQL, conn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

        While Not rs.EOF



            DirectorID = rs.Fields("DirectorID").Value
            DirectorFullName = rs.Fields("DirectorFullName").Value



            Console.WriteLine("Processing - " & DirectorFullName)

            strSQL = "SELECT DirectorFullName,Supervisor,Dept,CCLocation,HomeCostNumber,JobTitle,EMployee,PayDate,LogInTablet,LogOutTablet,ClockIn,ClockOut,FirstStop,LastStop,DiffMinIn,DiffMinOut FROM Operations.dbo.tLogClockComparisonReport WHERE DirectorID = '" & DirectorID & "'"
            rs2.Open(strSQL, conn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)


            'Open a workbook in Excel.
            Dim xlsApp As New Excel.Application
            Dim xlsWB As Excel.Workbook

            Dim xlsSheet As Object
            Dim xlsWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim strWorkBookPath As String

            OpenPath = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ExcelTemplatePath")

            strWorkBookPath = OpenPath

            xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(strWorkBookPath)
            xlsApp.Visible = False


            'Transfer the data to Excel.

            xlsSheet = xlsWB.Worksheets("Summary Data")
            xlsSheet.range("A2").CopyFromRecordset(rs2)
            xlsSheet = xlsWB.Worksheets("Summary - By Supervisor")
            xlsSheet.PivotTables("pvtSup").pivotcache.refresh()
            xlsSheet = xlsWB.Worksheets("Summary - By Site")
            xlsSheet.PivotTables("pvtSite").pivotcache.refresh()



            'HIDE SHEETS
            xlsSheet = xlsWB.Worksheets("Summary Data")
            xlsSheet.visible = False


            rs2.Close()

            'Save the workbook and quit Excel.
            xlsWB.SaveAs(createreportfolder & "\" & DateStamp & " - " & DirectorFullName)
            strFileName = createreportfolder & "\" & DateStamp & " - " & DirectorFullName & ".xlsx"
            xlsApp.Quit()
            'Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process

            xlsSheet = Nothing
            xlsWorkbook = Nothing

            xlsApp = Nothing

            rs.MoveNext()




        End While


    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Debug.Write(ex)
        Debug.Write(vbCrLf)
        Console.WriteLine("Excel Generator FAILED")
    End Try


    If Process.GetProcessesByName("excel").GetLength(0) > 0 Then

        For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")


            proc.Kill()
        Next
    End If

    GC.Collect()




    'Close the connection

    'conn.Close()





End Sub
```

`

Comment: Have you made sure that the scheduled task is running under a user account which can access the database?

Answer (score 0):

My IT department found the solution, oo posting it here for someone who may need it .
Create these two folders:
32Bit: 
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
64Bit:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
Excel needs these folders if it's not run interactively. Create both folders even if you are on a 64-bit OS.